# Extensions Disable/Uninstall when swapping devices

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I use VS Code remote on two separate devices, work laptop and home desktop. SSHing in with the same keys and same user.

As long as I SSH in from a single user, extensions continue to work without issue. The extensions are installed in the remote.

Once I connect from another device, the majority of extensions (python, etc.) either appear to be uninstalled, or are stuck in a disabled state.

Is there some way to make remote extensions work across any device?

Comment: [The new profiles feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_profiles)?

Answer (score 0):

I've just faced the same problem and it seems that's some sort of configuration problem in the SSH plugin. From [its official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh), the extensions shouldn't have to be installed again:

> While extensions that affect the VS Code UI, like themes and snippets, are installed locally, most extensions will reside on the SSH host. This ensures you have smooth experience and allows you to install any needed extensions for a given workspace on an SSH host from your local machine. This way, you can pick up exactly where you left off, from a different machine complete with your extensions.

Now, despite reinstalling many extensions, I observed that most of their data wasn't updated physically on the server (in linux, you can find them in ~/.vscode-server/extensions). What did change was the extensions.json file inside this folder, which merely contains the versions and timestamps of the installations.

So my conclusion is there's some bug related to the extension detection when connecting to a server for the first time. It might be related to having different vscode versions in each client. I thought about posting an issue on vscode's github, but it seems there was already a [similar one](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176275) opened at the time of this post.